# Google App Engine: cv2 libSM.so.6 error on Flask app

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, ubuntu, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have a Flask app that I want to deploy on the Google App Engine. Everything checks out fine, the requirements file contains all the modules which get installed successfully. But towards the end I get this error:

```
from .cv2 import *
ImportError: libSM.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I read on various blogs and other similar stackoverflow questions that you need to install libsm6 using:

`sudo apt-get install libsm6`

But even after I did that, I still get the same error. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The App Engine runtime has a fixed set of [system packages](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/reference/system-packages) that are included in the runtime and unfortunately `libsm6` is not one of them. In addition, it's not possible to install additional system packages.

However, this is an ideal use case for [Cloud Run](http://cloud.google.com/run/), which lets you define your own runtime via a `Dockerfile`. See the quickstart for an example: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/build-and-deploy

Comment: So in the Dockerfile, I add a ```RUN apt-get install libsm6``` and it should work right?